# how to loop rows in tasm assembly programming

Tags: loops, assembly, tasm, dosbox

I just need some help with regards to looping in tasm. I am trying to make a chessboard to be displayed on dos box screen in tasm. I have the following code that shows the first line with the colors.

```
TITLE screen1.ASM
DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 0100H
.DATA
.CODE
start:
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    MOV AX, 0600h           ;clear the screen for the program
    MOV BH, 07h
    MOV CX, 0000h
    MOV DX, 184Fh
    INT 10h


    MOV AH, 02h     ; move to upper left cursor
    MOV BH, 00h
    MOV DH, 00h
    MOV DL, 00h
    INT 10h

    MOV AH,09h      ;display blue x15 columns
    MOV AL, ' '
    mov BH, 00h
    MOV BL, 30h
    MOV CX, 0Fh
    INT 10h

    MOV AH, 02h     ; move to upper left 15th column cursor
    MOV BH, 00h
    MOV DH, 00h
    MOV DL, 0Fh
    INT 10h

    MOV AH,09h          ;display red x15 columns
    MOV AL, ''
    mov BH, 00h
    MOV BL, 45h
    MOV CX, 0Fh
    INT 10h

    MOV AH, 02h     ; move to upper left 30th column cursor
    MOV BH, 00h
    MOV DH, 00h
    MOV DL, 1Eh
    INT 10h

    MOV AH,09h          ;display blue again
    MOV AL, ''
    mov BH, 00h
    MOV BL, 30h
    MOV CX, 0Fh
    INT 10h

    MOV AH, 02h     ; move to upper left 45th column cursor
    MOV BH, 00h
    MOV DH, 00h
    MOV DL, 2Dh
    INT 10h

    MOV AH,09h          ;display red x15 columns
    MOV AL, ''
    mov BH, 00h
    MOV BL, 45h
    MOV CX, 0Fh
    INT 10h

    MOV AH, 02h     ; move to upper left 30th column cursor
    MOV BH, 00h
    MOV DH, 00h
    MOV DL, 3Ch
    INT 10h

    MOV AH,09h          ;display blue again
    MOV AL, ''
    mov BH, 00h
    MOV BL, 30h
    MOV CX, 0Fh
    INT 10h


    MOV AX,4C00h
    INT 21h
END start
```

the above code is well and all working but I have been trying to loop the above code 4 times to make the first row in a chessboard. I tried some looping code below but all it does is show the first line.

```
.MODEL SMALL

.STACK 100h

.DATA   
Finished DB 10, 13, 'Loopfinished.  Congratulations! $', 10, 13

.CODE

MAIN PROC

        MOV AX, @data            
        MOV DS, AX



        MOV CX, 4              
        MOV BX, 0                ; 


StrtLoop:                        ; When a loop starts, it does CX-- (subtracts 1 from CX) 

        INC BX                    ; This does BX++, which increments BX by 1

        MOV AH, 02h     ; move to upper left cursor
        MOV BH, 00h
        MOV DH, 00h
        MOV DL, 00h
        INT 10h

        MOV AH,09h      ;display blue x15 columns
        MOV AL, ' '
        mov BH, 00h
        MOV BL, 30h
        MOV CX, 0Fh
        INT 10h

        MOV AH, 02h     ; move to upper left 15th column cursor
        MOV BH, 00h
        MOV DH, 00h
        MOV DL, 0Fh
        INT 10h

        MOV AH,09h          ;display red x15 columns
        MOV AL, ''
        mov BH, 00h
        MOV BL, 45h
        MOV CX, 0Fh
        INT 10h

        MOV AH, 02h     ; move to upper left 30th column cursor
        MOV BH, 00h
        MOV DH, 00h
        MOV DL, 1Eh
        INT 10h

        MOV AH,09h          ;display blue again
        MOV AL, ''
        mov BH, 00h
        MOV BL, 30h
        MOV CX, 0Fh
        INT 10h

        MOV AH, 02h     ; move to upper left 45th column cursor
        MOV BH, 00h
        MOV DH, 00h
        MOV DL, 2Dh
        INT 10h

        MOV AH,09h          ;display red x15 columns
        MOV AL, ''
        mov BH, 00h
        MOV BL, 45h
        MOV CX, 0Fh
        INT 10h

        MOV AH, 02h     ; move to upper left 30th column cursor
        MOV BH, 00h
        MOV DH, 00h
        MOV DL, 3Ch
        INT 10h

        MOV AH,09h          ;display blue again
        MOV AL, ''
        mov BH, 00h
        MOV BL, 30h
        MOV CX, 0Fh
        INT 10h



LOOP StrtLoop                     ; Go back to StrtLoop label

        CMP BX, 4              ; Compare BX 
        JE DispMsg               ; Jump-if-Equal...CMP BX, 100 sets flags, and if they are set,
                                 ;  JE will Jump you to DispMsg (to get "congratulations" message).

        JMP SkipMsg              ; Jump to the SkipMsg label (so you don't see the "congratulations" message).

DispMsg:                         ; If BX = 100, you JE here.
        MOV AH, 09H              ; Displays the message stored in the defined byte "Finished"
        MOV DX, OFFSET Finished
        INT 21H



SkipMsg:                         ; If BX != 100, you JMP here.
        MOV AL, 0h               ; Op code to exit to DOS from the assembler.
        MOV AH, 4CH
        INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: 1) All of your interrupt function arguments in the loop are hardcoded, so they'll be the same for every iteration of the loop. 2) You're modifying `CX` inside the loop without saving and retoring it.

Comment: Your loop also clobbers `BH` and `BL`, so the `inc BX` is useless, too.  Since you need to make several different `int 10h` calls, you probably can't use any of the parameter registers as a loop counter directly.  Use a different reg (like `SI`), and copy it where needed.  I assume `int 10h` preserves all registers.